# How to set android client time zone same as server timezone in twilio client sdk

Tags: android, timezone, twilio

I am generating capability token by using server code

```
   <?php
include "vendor/autoload.php";

use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;

// put your Twilio API credentials here
$accountSid = 'AC5fb1760ee03546b8747b7ff9c10c0c85';
$authToken  = 'your_auth_token';
$appSid = 'APXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming('jenny');
$token = $capability->generateToken();

echo $token;
```

and immediately showing

> JWT token expired(31205)

when run the android client sdk I have searched in **twilio** stating that

> make sure your server time clock is set up correctly ..
>   https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180948-Capability-token-is-expired

Now how to set time zone in android client? Please tell how to do that or how to make correct token?

Comment: How are you generating the JWT?

Comment: Can you update your question rather than adding comments. Also, don't post your auth token!

Comment: @philnash Can u please see the updated question

Comment: Timestamps in JWT are all based on UTC, so changing the time zone is irrelevant.  Where did you see it stated that you should change the timezone?  Edit your question to provide a link please.

Comment: I'll also point out that your question has [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534).

Comment: The problem isn't the Android client's time zone. The token is generated on your server, so that might be the one that's causing the problem. If you want to send an example token to me at philnash@twilio.com then I can take a look.

Comment: @philnash i have sent a mail with token please check.